# Email HTML image repeating in outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

So I am testing out some emails that will be sent to customers/users and I am seeing that outlook doesn't render the background image well, its repeating it.

I have searched and tried certain things like:

- https://backgrounds.cm/
- I tryed to replace fill="f" & fill type="frame" to "t" & "tile" but still getting the same result.
- I have changed the width & height to be the same as  or  or the picture itself.
- Tried to change the CSS background-repeat:no-repeat; moved it around all the ways I know of
- Tryed to replace the "v:background" to "v:rect"
- Now I'm here :)

I'm seeing that this is a known issue but I can't seem to find a way that works for me.

I really appreciate any help or info in the right direction!

**Here is the actual HTML I am using:**

```
<body style="padding:0; margin:0; display:block; background:#ffffff; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
       <tr>
            <td background="http://i.imgur.com/uu9hFXR.png" 
                bgcolor="#E3E6C6" 
                valign="top" 
                style="background: url(http://i.imgur.com/uu9hFXR.png); 
                background-repeat:no-repeat; 
                background-color: #E3E6C6; 
                background-position: center;">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="f">
                    <v:fill type="frame" src="http://i.imgur.com/uu9hFXR.png" color="#E3E6C6"/>
                    </v:background>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Kind regards!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx#Word2007MailHTMLandCSS_Full note that Outlook does not support background-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) list Outlook.com and Outlook 2007/2013 does not support `background-repeat`

Comment: Thank you both for the sources (bookmarked). But if its not supported, and i tryed with "v:rect" with what options am i left ?  Kind regards !

Comment: Why is everyone ignoring me ? ... Kind regards

Comment: @lucdebevere Make you email as simple as possible. You can always include url to your site where user can view fully styled message

Comment: Well its not a artwork i mean its just a logo, text and a button/link and it works for most emails except outlook ... I like the idea of creating a page on the site for it (thats why i am marking that as answer) as much as i like UI friendly steps if nobody can figure this out or doesn't want to help i will have to just ignore it for outlook users ... Kind regards and thank you for those that shared the info/links !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the image in the background and then calling it again in style="background:...".

Have you tried removing one of those two ref'd images in the table?

Comment: Yeah i thought that too but when i **1)** remove the first url in the <td> and leave the 2 others (the one declared in the style="" & the one in the <v:...> there is no background at all. if i **2)** remove the 2nd one (in the style"") its repeating the background. and **3)** removing 2nd and the one in in the <v:...> its also repeating ... this only happens for outlook. in others its working fine.  Kind regards

Comment: No body has any idea ? I literally spended 12hours already testing it each time, i tryed so many things but only outlook is given me a hard time... Please any help is greatly apreciated ! Kind regards

Comment: Does nobody has any suggestions ? Kind regards

Comment: So what there is no way of doing it for outlook? I receive emails in outlook with images so there's got to be a way ... ? 
Kind regards